# Upload Multiple Files Using React, NodeJS with Express & Multer

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, express, multer

I want to upload multiple files from my React Application using the formData, I want each uploaded file to be stored in my main root directory named "uploads" and separate each file into different directory (for example, the first file would be stored in directory "1", the second file would be stored in directory "2", etc...).
I'm using React for Client side, and NodeJS for Server side with Express and Multer.
Someone can help?
Thank you :)

I have managed to upload the files into "uploads" root directory but no success to separate each file to different directory.